# Update Text Inside Page With Image

Tags: javascript, html, delphi, delphi-7

I am working with Delphi7 and TEmbeddedWB. I have some difficulty to update text of a page in twebbrowser. Because that webpage contains images. So Complete Html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">'#$D#$A'
<HTML>
    <HEAD>'#$D#$A'
        <META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type>'#$D#$A'
        <META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.7601.17514">
    </HEAD>'#$D#$A'
    <BODY>'#$D#$A'
       <DIV align=center><**IMG '#$D#$A'src="file:///C:/Program%20Files/image/c.jpg"></DIV>
       <FONT '#$D#$A'size=2 face=Arial><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">'#$D#$A'<P>**Hello «Forename», '#$D#$A'thiss<BR><BR><BR>«signature»<BR>**</P></SPAN></FONT>
    </BODY>
</HTML>'#$D#$A.
```

So I need to update only text like from (Hello «Forename» this «signature») to (this is a demo page). When I go to set Doc.Body.innerText := this is a demo page. Then On showing page image does remove, only text is display.

Please tell me how would be update text inside page with image. Please help me

Comment: Doc.Body.innerText replaces the complete contents of the body element, so that makes sense.

Comment: Maybe you can use innerHTML instead and use StringReplace to replace the name and signature markers. In that case you are still replacing the entire page body, but it might just work. I don't know TEmbeddedWB myself, but it probably had methods or exposes interfaces that let you manipulate the document in a more refined way.

Comment: thanks  GolezTrol . But EmbeddedWB does not have StringReplace property. could you give me another suggestion. ? Please.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the StringReplace function of Delphi to replace the text in the HTML of the browser, so something like:

```
Doc.Body.innerHTML := StringReplace(Doc.Body.innerHTML, '«signature»', 'Your Signature', []);
```

innerHTML should return the body contents, including all elements, while innerText only gets the text, without markup.

A nicer way would be to use methods like getElementById and other similar methods that you have available in e.g. Javascript, but I don't know if those methods are exposed by TEmbeddedWB.

Comment: Thanks GolezTrol. I have used your solution, but still it will remove image. If I use getElementById like (<P>) method for above html script. But It is not sure next script has (<P>) or not. Please is there any way in java script for change only text. Please help me.

Comment: Hi GolezTrol, I am implementing spell checker on html page. if u have any demos for doing this task please share me. And you have any idea behind this please tell me. I am very thankfully to you.